# XSLT transform of Youtube Channel feed with namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, youtube

How would I get the entry/media:thumbnail/url value in my html table.

Feed XML:

```
<feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <link rel="self" href="http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=MyChannel"/>
  <id>yt:channel:MyChannel</id>
  <yt:channelId>MyChannel</yt:channelId>
  <title>Jon Smith</title>
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/MyChannel"/>
  <author>
    <name>Jon Smith</name>
    <uri>
      https://www.youtube.com/channel/MyChannel
    </uri>
  </author>
  <published>2007-02-13T04:11:08+00:00</published>
  <entry>
    <id>yt:video:BQrqsddkSuI_Uo</id>
    <yt:videoId>BQrqsskSuI_Uo</yt:videoId>
    <yt:channelId>MyChannel</yt:channelId>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQrqsddkSusdfdI_Uo"/>
    <author>
      <name>Jon Smith</name>
      <uri>
        https://www.youtube.com/channel/MyChannel
      </uri>
    </author>
    <published>2017-07-26T17:41:31+00:00</published>
    <updated>2017-08-07T11:17:33+00:00</updated>
    <media:group>
      <media:title>Title 1</media:title>
      <media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/BQrqsddskSuI_Uo?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/>
      <media:thumbnail url="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/BQrqksdsdSuI_Uo/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
      <media:description>Description 1.</media:description>
      <media:community>
        <media:starRating count="1" average="5.00" min="1" max="5"/>
        <media:statistics views="13"/>
      </media:community>
    </media:group>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>yt:video:uhAXp6sdfsddRnSA</id>
    <yt:videoId>uhAXp6sdfsdRnSA</yt:videoId>
    <yt:channelId>MyChannel</yt:channelId>
    <title>
      Title 2
    </title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhAXsdsdp6dRnSA"/>
    <author>
      <name>Jon Smith</name>
      <uri>
        https://www.youtube.com/channel/MyChannel
      </uri>
    </author>
    <published>2014-10-28T21:39:27+00:00</published>
    <updated>2017-07-26T17:42:27+00:00</updated>
    <media:group>
      <media:title>
        Title 2
      </media:title>
      <media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/uhAXp6dRnsddSA?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/>
      <media:thumbnail url="https://i2.ytimg.com/vi/uhAXp6dsdsdRnSA/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
      <media:description>Description 2</media:description>
      <media:community>
        <media:starRating count="0" average="0.00" min="1" max="5"/>
        <media:statistics views="25"/>
      </media:community>
    </media:group>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="feed">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My Videos</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Image URL</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="entry">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="media:thumbnail/@url"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You need to rename the namespaces (default or otherwise) from the source XML file in your XSLT file.

So in the source file, you have the namespaces of: `xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`

So add these to your XSLT file as well...however....you must give the default `xmlns` an explicit prefix. So I gave it a `d`,  as in default. So in the XSLT, for that namespace, you'll have `xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`

Final XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" >
<xsl:template match="d:feed">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My Videos</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title<xsl:value-of select="d:id"/></th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Image URL</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="d:entry">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="d:title"/></td>
      <td><img>
             <xsl:attribute name="src">
                 <xsl:value-of select='media:group/media:thumbnail/@url'/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </img>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Was just about to answer with exactly the same but with a non `<xsl:for-each>`!